# (Python 3.6.4)Im using the 'z' var as the user input. It gives me an error about this and ignores the other "if" statements

Tags: python

I am working on a simple calculator. I started Python 3 three days ago. I was very happy making this code. It is supposed to be able to add, subtract, multiply, and divide 10 numbers.

I was working on the adding part of it, which works completely fine. However, it gives me a NameError when I try to subtract, multiply, and divide numbers.

The code starts by asking the user if they would like to use the calculator. If you say no, it stops the code. If you say yes, it asks if you would like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide.

If you say add, you can add up to 10 numbers (not finished yet). If you say any of the others, it gives a NameError saying,

```
if z in [2]:
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for about 1 hour now. I've done research, and couldn't find the issue. I use Python 3.6.4. It would be great if anyone could help me out on this. Thanks.

FYI: Don't forget, I'm not done with this code. Yes, it's supposed to be able to work with 10 numbers in the end, but I found this problem and didn't want to make it any worse. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
#New Code
print("Welcome to this simple calculator")
#Yes/No
a = input("Would you like to use this simple calculator?(Yes/No):")
print(a + ' confirmed')

if a in ["No","no"]:
    print("Come back next time!!")
    raise SystemExit

if a in ["Yes","yes"]:
    b = input("Would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?")
#Add
if b in ["Add", "add"]:
    z = float(input("How many numbers would you like to add?(2-10):"))
    if z in [2]:
        c = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
        d = float(input("Enter another number to add:"))
        print("The result is", + c + d)
        print("Come back next time!!")
        if z in [3]:
            k = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
            t = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
            s = float(input("Enter another number to add:"))
            print("The result is", + k + t + s)
            print("Come back next time!!")
            if z in [4]:
                n = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                m = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                w = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                r = float(input("Enter another number to add:"))
                print("The result is", + n + m + w + r)
                print("Come back next time!")
                if z in [5]:
                    o = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                    p = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                    l = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                    v = float(input("Enter a number to add:"))
                    u = float(input("Enter another number to add:"))
                    print("The result is", + o + p + l + v + u)
                    print("Come back next time!")


if b in ["Subtract", "subtract"]:
    e = float(input("Enter a number to subtract:"))
    f = float(input("Enter another number to subtract:"))
    print("The result is", + e - f)
    print("Come back next time!!")

if b in ["Multiply","multiply"]:
    g = float(input("Enter a number to multiply:"))
    h = float(input("Enter another number to multiply:"))
    print("The result is", + g * h)
    print("Come back next time!!")

if b in ["Divide","divide"]:
    i = float(input("Enter a number to divide:"))
    j = float(input("Enter another number to divide:"))
    print("The result is", + i / j)
    print("Come back next time!!")
```

Comment: Did you inputted the value of `z`? Possibly not, because your `b` might NOT be equal to "Add" or "add"

Comment: You have bad indentation in your posted code, which is critical in Python. Your lines `if z in ` should be indented under the `if b in ["Add", "add"]:` line. If that is the case in your actual code, add the indentation and try again. If they are indented in your actual code, change the posted code here to match.

Comment: Just posted the new code

Comment: It fixes the problem about the NameError, but now the adding is the problem. When it asks how many numbers I want to add, the code stops working.

Comment: you probably want the read in value to be an int not a float.   also you don't need to add to the indenting on all the greater than 2 items.  they can all be at the same indenting level as the 2.  I would suggest also for the 3,4,5... etc that they be else if so that if any one branch is taken the others do not need to be evaluated.

Comment: If I enter 2 when it asks, it works, if I enter 3, 4, or 5, it stops.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that then see how it works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed the problem! Have a happy New Years.